# Insert text value starting with @ with Jquery where razor is active?

Tags: jquery, string, razor

I am trying to insert the term @UserName into a CKEditor so that i may replace it at a later stage.

Whilst trying to insert the string the @ sign is highlighted in yellow as its expecting razor markup.

[image]

basic example

```
$('#SomeTextInput').val("@sometext");
```

Comment: Where should you get UserName from? shows us your code

Comment: It does not mater, the text could be @Sometext. I just need to know how to insert text starting with @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use @@ instead of @ @@ is the escape char for @ in razor code your cde would look something like

```
CKEditor.insteance[..].insertText('@@Hi there')
```